# Nodes not starting. Jar manifest missing

Tags: corda

I am not not able to start nodes on a Linux server
I am getting the following (edited) output

```
[user@host nodes]$ ./runnodes
which: no osascript in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/bin)
Starting nodes in /opt/nodes
Starting corda.jar in /opt/nodes/NodeA on debug port 5005
Starting corda-webserver.jar in /opt/nodes/Agent on debug port 5006
Starting corda.jar in /opt/nodes/NodeB on debug port 5007
Starting corda-webserver.jar in /opt/nodes/NodeB on debug port 5008
Starting corda.jar in /opt/nodes/NodeC on debug port 5009
Starting corda-webserver.jar in /opt/nodes/NodeC on debug port 5010
Starting corda.jar in /opt/nodes/NodeZ on debug port 5011
Starting corda-webserver.jar in /opt/nodes/NodeZ on debug port 5012
Started 8 processes
Finished starting nodes
[user@host nodes]$ Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /home/user/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_0.12.1/quasar-core-0.7.6-jdk8.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /home/user/.capsule/apps/net.corda.node.Corda_0.12.1/quasar-core-0.7.6-jdk8.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /home/user/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_0.12.1/quasar-core-0.7.6-jdk8.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /home/user/.capsule/apps/net.corda.node.Corda_0.12.1/quasar-core-0.7.6-jdk8.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /home/user/.capsule/apps/net.corda.webserver.WebServer_0.12.1/quasar-core-0.7.6-jdk8.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /home/user/.capsule/apps/net.corda.node.Corda_0.12.1/quasar-core-0.7.6-jdk8.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5012
Unknown command line arguments: no-local-shell is not a recognized option
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5011
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/user/.capsule/apps/net.corda.node.Corda_0.12.1/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/nodes/NodeZ/dependencies/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

What am I missing to start these nodes?

Comment: Did you check permissions on the files?

Comment: Yes 644 rw-r--r--

Answer (score 1):

Did you build the nodes on Mac, than transfer them to Linux? If so, try building the nodes directly on the Linux machine.